# Dotnet Core / SignalR communication

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

My WebApp run on dotnet core 2.2.7 and im using AspNet.SingalR 2.4.1.

In my local environment, when I run my WebApp, it works well, with this log in the console : 
[image: expected behavious]
When I run on my server (Windows server 2016, hosted on IIS), signarR try to connect with SEE (Not  WebSocket ?) Why ? And send this error :

> signalr.js:1883 Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error:
>   Server returned handshake error: Handshake was canceled.'.

[image: actual behavious]

Comment: So you are hosting in IIS?

Comment: Yes, I'll update the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that you have `WebSockets` enabled on the server.

[image: websockets on server]

Also you can check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-websocket-protocol-support).

Comment: Ok, thanks, it was disabled, but now I have another error : ``signalr.js:2746 WebSocket connection to 'ws://10.57.42.36/hubs/BigScreenHub?id=-v3N' failed: Establishing a tunnel via proxy server failed.``

Comment: Anyways, an exception was missing in m proxy configuration thanks