# SignalR: foreverFrame transport timed out when trying to connect

Tags: signalr

I'm using SignalR and SQLDependency. When there is a change on server, clients will be notified. 
On Client side:

```
var job = $.connection.processLogHub;

$.connection.hub.logging = true;
$.connection.hub.transportConnectTimeout = 3000;

job.client.displayLastUpdate = function (displayLastUpdate) {
    displayProcessLogChangeNotification(displayLastUpdate);
};

job.client.displayJobsLocked = function (realTimeLockedJobs) {
    displayJobsLockedUnlocked(realTimeLockedJobs);        
};

$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
}).fail(function (e) {

    alert('error signalr : ' + e);
    console.log(e);

}); 

$.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
    console.log("$.connection.hub.disconnected");
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("restart");
        $.connection.hub.start();
    }, 1000);
});
```

Server side:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
            GlobalHost.Configuration.TransportConnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        }
    }
```

ProcessLogHub class:

```
public class ProcessLogHub : Hub
    {
        public static void DisplayLastUpdate(string lastUpdateDate)
        {
            IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ProcessLogHub>();
            context.Clients.All.displayLastUpdate(lastUpdateDate);
        }

        public static void DisplayJobsLocked(IEnumerable<RealtimeLockedJob> realTimeLockedJobs)
        {
            IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ProcessLogHub>();
            context.Clients.All.displayJobsLocked(realTimeLockedJobs);
        }
    }
```

This code is sometimes working well. But sometimes suddenly it does not work anymore and give me the below log :

```
[15:12:27 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'processloghub'.
[15:12:27 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Negotiating with '/JMT/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=2.1&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22processloghub%22%7D%5D'.
[15:12:27 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Negotiating with '/JMT/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=2.1&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22processloghub%22%7D%5D'.
[15:12:28 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: serverSentEvents transport starting.
[15:12:28 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: This browser doesn't support SSE.
[15:12:28 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: serverSentEvents transport failed to connect. Attempting to fall back.
[15:12:28 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: foreverFrame transport starting.
[15:12:28 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Binding to iframe's load event.
[15:12:41 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: foreverFrame transport timed out when trying to connect.
[15:12:41 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Stopping forever frame.
[15:12:41 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: foreverFrame transport failed to connect. Attempting to fall back.
[15:12:41 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: longPolling transport starting.
[15:12:41 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Opening long polling request to 'https://pprd-entrypoint.bell.ca/JMT/signalr/connect?transport=longPolling&clientProtocol=2.1&connectionToken=ZtAV8xQcGKXtBY%2F2Ke3J12DeAYy3QQMirAWzzY4%2FeAW2oX1JeNkg6heTD%2BPUL8nnfgi6MoKl%2Fd1YliMMN6euu0YyLf7uBs02LQ7GsDb%2Fe9MDHrcD4SYESNHbfK3cZxzm&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22processloghub%22%7D%5D'.
[15:12:41 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Long poll complete.
[15:12:41 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: longPolling transport failed to connect. Attempting to fall back.
[15:12:41 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Fallback transports exhausted.
Error: No transport could be initialized successfully. Try specifying a different transport or none at all for auto initialization.
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: {
         [functions]: ,
         __proto__: {
            [functions]: ,
            __proto__: null
         },
         message: "",
         name: "Error"
      },
      description: "No transport could be initialized successfully. Try specifying a different transport or none at all for auto initialization.",
      message: "No transport could be initialized successfully. Try specifying a different transport or none at all for auto initialization.",
      name: "Error",
      source: undefined
   }
[15:13:36 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Stopping connection.
[15:13:36 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Fired ajax abort async = true.
[15:13:36 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: LongPolling failed to connect.
[15:13:36 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Failed to parse server response while attempting to connect.
Unable to get property 'hub' of undefined or null reference
```

In the successful case the foreverFrame can connect to server:

```
[16:27:38 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: foreverFrame transport connected. Initiating start request.
[16:27:38 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: The start request succeeded. Transitioning to the connected state.
[16:27:38 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Now monitoring keep alive with a warning timeout of 13333.333333333332, keep alive timeout of 20000 and disconnecting timeout of 30000
```

Could you tell me why SignalR  foreverFrame work on and off and how can I fix it? 
Is it because I'm using 2 event for the notification?
Thank you

Comment: Why you don't use webSockets? Is it a requirement to connect with foreverFrame?

Comment: Hi @Kiril1512, no it's not a requirement. I tried to use websocket but IE didn't use it even serversentevent. I tried to search websocket configuration on IIS but there are a lot of things. Do you have a simple guide to configure websocket on IIS? Because it's not me who do the configuration but another person, I don't want to give him a long instruction. Thanks

Comment: I answered a question about WebSockets on IIS and it have the link to configuration, you can check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60927562/dotnet-core-signalr-communication/60929834#60929834

Comment: hi @Kiril1512, I set up IIS to support websocket as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/webSocket. and in webconfi I put <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />. But in the log I see
SignalR: webSockets transport starting.
SignalR: Connecting to websocket endpoint 'wss://
SignalR: webSockets transport timed out when trying to connect.
Closing the Websocket.

Comment: So we can see that this happens even with ```wss```, so the transport type is not the problem. Have you tried to remove the timeout configuration on the server to see if it can connect with default values?

Comment: hi @Kiril1512, before, I didn't put timeout on server. Then I thought, maybe the problem happens because it's timed out. So I extended the timeout. I've just had a doubt. Is it because I put
<%: Scripts.Render("Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.1.min.js") %>
    <%: Scripts.Render("signalr/hubs") %> at the end of MasterPage?

Comment: No idea then...